# hakmem algorithm

Tags: c#

I see this hakmem algorithm:

```
int pop(unsigned x) {
  unsigned n;

  n = (x >> 1) & 0x77777777;
  x = x - n;
  n = (n >> 1) & 0x77777777;
  x = x - n;
  n = (n >> 1) & 0x77777777;
  x = x - n;
  x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
  x = x * 0x01010101;
  return x >> 24;
}
```

Is possible change it for a long of 64 bits?

Comment: What problem do you see? Have you at least **tried** changing the variable types to LONG and extending the hexnumbers to be 64bit instead of 32bit? (and the '24' to proper one..)

Comment: Also, please expand the information about which algorithm it is. HAKMEM is a compendium of many various algorithms!

Comment: That counts the number of 1 bits in an unsigned int. "pop" in this context means "population count", which is the computer science term for the number of 1 bits.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating what is known as the "Hamming weight", which for integers means the number of binary "1" bits in the number. For binary numbers, this is also known as the "population count".

There are several ways to implement this for 64 bits.

[Please see the Wiki page for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).

Here's an implementation [stolen from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960434/c-population-count-of-unsigned-64-bit-integer-with-a-maximum-value-of-15):

```
public int Pop(ulong w) 
{
    w -= (w >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555UL;
    w = (w & 0x3333333333333333UL) + ((w >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333UL);
    w = (w + (w >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fUL;
    return (int)((w * 0x0101010101010101UL) >> 56);
}
```